# Array building in Python

Tags: python

I have an array like this in a data file:

```
0   822.6   1391.3  1
0   822.6   1391.3  2
0   708.3   1501.2  3
0   708.3   1501.2  4
0   632.5   1585.8  5
0   632.5   1585.8  6
0   552.4   1652.6  7
0   552.4   1652.6  8
250 850.8   1358.6  1
250 803.3   1406.2  2
250 732.0   1481.9  3
250 694.9   1519    4
250 642.9   1566.5  5
250 613.2   1594.7  6
250 570.2   1637.8  7
250 537.5   1663    8
```

I want to create separate data sets depending on the last column.

In other words I want something like this:

```
while data[:,3] != 9:
    if data[:,3] == 1:
        x1 = data[:,0]
        y1= (data[:,1]-data[:,2])**2
    if data[:,3] == 2:
        x2 = data[:,0]
        y2= (data[:,1]-data[:,2])**2
```

And so on... 
I only put does not equal 9 because I only have from `1-8` in the last column always.

I know this is completely wrong, but I need help.

Comment: Sorry .. like x1,y1 array will correspond to the data when the last column is 1. x2,y2 will be when it equals 2, and so on.

Comment: What type of object is `data`? You can't index a regular list with tuples, and you can't subtract them, and you can't square them.

Comment: @Kevin: that's not a tuple; that's a subtraction in parentheses.

Comment: just a data.dat file with those entries as indicated.

Comment: I was looking for something like "`data` is a dictionary" or "It's a numpy array". I already know your data is in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
a = array([[ 0.64910219,  0.06868991, -0.34844128,  0.        ],
           [-1.34767042, -1.77338287,  0.693539  ,  1.        ],
           [ 1.31245883, -2.08879047, -0.83514187,  3.        ],
           [ 0.43156959,  0.31388795,  0.2856625 ,  1.        ],
           [-0.60531108, -0.63226693,  0.32063803,  2.        ],
           [-0.47538621, -0.64196643, -0.82296546,  3.        ],
           [ 0.3491207 , -1.25406403,  1.21754411,  0.        ],
           [-1.1573242 ,  1.1636706 ,  0.63733285,  2.        ]])

d0 = a[a[:,3]==0,:]
d1 = a[a[:,3]==1,:]
d2 = a[a[:,3]==2,:]
d3 = a[a[:,3]==3,:]
```

The variables d0, d1, d2, d3 contain the rows with the appropriate values in the right-most column.

```
>>> d0
array([[ 0.64910219,  0.06868991, -0.34844128,  0.        ],
       [ 0.3491207 , -1.25406403,  1.21754411,  0.        ]])
>>> d1
array([[-1.34767042, -1.77338287,  0.693539  ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.43156959,  0.31388795,  0.2856625 ,  1.        ]])
>>> d2
array([[-0.60531108, -0.63226693,  0.32063803,  2.        ],
       [-1.1573242 ,  1.1636706 ,  0.63733285,  2.        ]])
>>> d3
array([[ 1.31245883, -2.08879047, -0.83514187,  3.        ],
       [-0.47538621, -0.64196643, -0.82296546,  3.        ]])
```

To create the x1, y1, etc.. that you mention in the post, you just need to manipulate those arrays.

```
x1 = d1[:,0]
y1 = (d1[:,1] - d1[:,2])**2
```

And so on for the other values of the fourth column. For a small number of possible values (1 - 8), hardcoding the different variables isn't too bad, but this method can easily generalize to an arbitrary list with a list of the computed outputs.